# Android Studio project works fine on Lollipop but crashes while testing on KitKat devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My `android studio` project works finely on `lollipop` but crashes while testing on `kitkat` devices. it has a material view pager and while opening activity that has material view pager the app just force close on kit kat device.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.production.iedc.helo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.0.8@aar'){
        transitive=true

    }
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Well why does it crash? Log at the logcat.

Comment: Add your logcat.. 2resons fr crash, u using sme library which aint building in kitkat or the function/api u using smewer is nt supported by kitkat

Comment: can u check this i will update the question soon https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_RPq9qCBJHdaENLVmEtY1Zmcjg&usp=sharing

Comment: https://goo.gl/Ytmpw8 check this link for source file . someone please help me i am a newbie stuck on this part

Comment: The third party library that you are using are they compatible with KitKat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818903/my-android-studio-project-works-finely-on-lollipop-but-crashes-while-testing-on

Comment: i am using material view pager  by florence from github

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818903/my-android-studio-project-works-finely-on-lollipop-but-crashes-while-testing-on