# My android studio project works finely on lollipop but crashes while testing on kitkat devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, import

My android studio project works finely on lollipop but crashes while testing on kitkat devices. it has a material view pager and while opening activity that has material view pager the app just force close on kit kat device.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.production.iedc.helo, PID: 12711
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.production.iedc.helo/com.production.iedc.helo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                              at com.production.iedc.helo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

   Build.gradle

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.production.iedc.helo"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.0.8@aar'){
            transitive=true

        }
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
        compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }

Main activity

package com.production.iedc.helo;
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    MaterialViewPager materialViewPager;
    View headerLogo;
    ImageView headerLogoContent;
    DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //  Declare a new thread to do a preference check
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //  Initialize SharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

                //  Create a new boolean and preference and set it to true
                boolean isFirstStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

                //  If the activity has never started before...
                if (isFirstStart) {

                    //  Launch app intro
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DefaultIntro.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //  Make a new preferences editor
                    SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();

                    //  Edit preference to make it false because we don't want this to run again
                    e.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

                    //  Apply changes
                    e.apply();
                }
            }
        });


        // Start the thread
        t.start();



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //4 onglets
        final int tabCount = 4;

        //les vues définies dans @layout/header_logo
        headerLogo = findViewById(R.id.headerLogo);
        headerLogoContent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headerLogoContent);

        //le MaterialViewPager
        this.materialViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);
        toolbar = materialViewPager.getToolbar();
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
                actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, 0, 0);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        materialViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {


            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                //je créé pour chaque onglet un RecyclerViewFragment
                return RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
            }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return 4;
                }

                //le titre à afficher pour chaque page
                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    switch (position % 4) {
                        case 0:
                            return "ACADEMICS";
                        case 1:
                            return "NEWS FEEDS";
                        case 2:
                            return "EVENTS";
                        case 3:
                            return "MISC";
                        default:
                            return "Page " + position;
                    }

                }

                int oldItemPosition = -1;
                @Override
                public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

                    //seulement si la page est différente
                    if (oldItemPosition != position) {
                        oldItemPosition = position;

                        //définir la nouvelle couleur et les nouvelles images
                       Drawable imageUrl = null;
                        int color = Color.BLACK;
                        Drawable newDrawable = null;




                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                imageUrl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.academics);
                                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan);
                                newDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.earth);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                imageUrl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newsfeeds);
                                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
                                newDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tennis);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                imageUrl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.events);
                                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
                                newDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.evennt);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                imageUrl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.misc);
                                color = getResources().getColor(R.color.lime);
                                newDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light);
                                break;
                        }

                        //puis modifier les images/couleurs
                        int fadeDuration = 400;
                        materialViewPager.setColor(color, fadeDuration);
                        materialViewPager.setImageDrawable(imageUrl, fadeDuration);
                        toggleLogo(newDrawable,color,fadeDuration);

                    }
                }
            });

            //permet au viewPager de garder 4 pages en mémoire (à ne pas utiliser sur plus de 4 pages !)
            this.materialViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(tabCount);
            //relie les tabs au viewpager
            this.materialViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(this.materialViewPager.getViewPager());
        }

    private void toggleLogo(final Drawable newLogo, final int newColor, int duration){

        //animation de disparition
        final AnimatorSet animatorSetDisappear = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSetDisappear.setDuration(duration);
        animatorSetDisappear.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(headerLogo, "scaleX", 0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(headerLogo, "scaleY", 0)
        );

        //animation d'apparition
        final AnimatorSet animatorSetAppear = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSetAppear.setDuration(duration);
        animatorSetAppear.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(headerLogo, "scaleX", 1),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(headerLogo, "scaleY", 1)
        );

        //après la disparition
        animatorSetDisappear.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                //modifie la couleur du cercle
                ((GradientDrawable) headerLogo.getBackground()).setColor(newColor);

                //modifie l'image contenue dans le cercle
                headerLogoContent.setImageDrawable(newLogo);

                //démarre l'animation d'apparition
                animatorSetAppear.start();
            }
        });

        //démarre l'animation de disparition
        animatorSetDisappear.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) ||
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

Activitylayout.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:viewpager_logo="@layout/header_logo"
        app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/material_view_pager_pagertitlestrip_newstand"
        app:viewpager_logoMarginTop="100dp"
        app:viewpager_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:viewpager_headerHeight="200dp"
        app:viewpager_headerAlpha="0.6"
        app:viewpager_hideLogoWithFade="false"
        app:viewpager_hideToolbarAndTitle="true"
        app:viewpager_enableToolbarElevation="true"
        app:viewpager_parallaxHeaderFactor="1.5"
        app:viewpager_headerAdditionalHeight="20dp"
        app:viewpager_displayToolbarWhenSwipe="true"
       app:viewpager_transparentToolbar="true"
        app:viewpager_animatedHeaderImage="true"

        />

    <include layout="@layout/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

Comment: i use that theme as base theme

Comment: i am newbie .. stuck on this now can u help me

Comment: the entire project is here      
https://goo.gl/Ytmpw8

Answer (score 0):

you should change the inheritance of java use

### ActionBarActivity

to

### Activity

and leave the dialog theme in the manifest as it is. i think you will not have the problem.

Comment: if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

these codes fails to work